# Let linear system $Ax=b$, $x\in R^n$ and $b\in R^m$ with $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with $m<n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let linear system $Ax=b$, $x\in R^n$ and $b\in R^m$ with $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with $m<n$.

> **Theorem**
>   $\forall b\in R^m$, the system is solveable if and only if $\det(AA^H)\neq 0$.

Solution for this system is given by formula $x=A^H(AA^H)^{-1}$
Where $A^H$ is the transpose of $A$

To proof the theorem given

> **Lemma**. Let $W$ and $Z$ be Hilbert spaces, $G \in L(W,Z)$ and $G^H L(Z,W)$ the adjoint operator, then the
>   following statements holds:
>   (i) $\mathrm{Rang}(G) = Z \iff \exists\gamma  > 0$ such that
>         $$ \|G^Hz\|_W≥\gamma\|z\|_Z,\qquad z \in Z $$
>   (ii) $\overline{\mathrm{Rang}(G)} = Z \iff \ker (G^H) = 0 \iff G^H$ is one to one.

Proof:

The matrix $A$ may also viewed as a linear operator $A\colon \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^m\to\R^n$; therefore $A \in L(\R^m,\R^n)$ and adjoint operator $A^H$ is the transpose of $A$ and $A^H\colon \R^n\to\R^m$. Then, the system is solvable for all $b \in \R^n$ if and only if, the operator $A$ is surjective. Hence, from the this
then there exists $\gamma > 0$ such that
$$ \|A^Hz\|_{\R^n}≥\gamma\|z\|_{\R^m}, \qquad z \in \R^m$$
Therefore,
$$ \langle AA^Hz,z\rangle≥\gamma^2 ‖z‖_{\R^m}^2,\qquad z∈\R^m $$

This implies that $AA^H$ is one to one. Since $AA^H$ is a $m \times m$ matrix, then $\det(AA^H)\ne 0$.

Someone can explain this for me!

Comment: What is your question? $\det(AA^T)\neq 0$ is not true for $A=0$.

Comment: Your first claim is false, even if the matrix is non-zero. For example:$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\2&2&2\end{pmatrix}\implies \det\left(AA^t\right)=\begin{vmatrix}3&6\\6&12\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Comment: How about the row vectors are linear independence?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof obviously fails if $A$ is not of full rank (for example, if $A=0$, then $\det(AA^T)$ is obviously $0$).

Your proof also has other issues. For example, you claim

> Then, the system is solvable for all $b \in \R^n$ if and only if, the operator $A$ is surjective.

but I, as a reader, have no idea what this *system* you are talking about is. You didn't define any system before claiming that it is solvable, so your proof needs work.

Furthermore, you claim that $\mathrm{Ran}(G)=Z$, but you haven't defined what $\mathrm{Ran}$ is, so again, I cannot tell you if the lemma you claim to use is wrong or not, because I don't know what it is claiming.

Comment: Theorem. For all b∈R^n , the system Ax=b with A be m by n matrix and m<n is solvable if, and only if,
det (AA^H) ≠ 0.

Comment: @exfresh Sure. Now what does that have to do with anything? Where does the theorem come in, and what do you use it for? I suggest you edit your original question to make the proof more clear.

Comment: Ok, done edited.

Comment: @exfresh What's $\mathrm{Rang}$?

Comment: I don't understand, but the article write like that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the statement you want to prove is wrong. If $A = 0$, for example, we have $\det(AA^t) = \det 0 = 0$. You probably forgot to include the hypothesis on $A$ being one-to-one, or equivalently, of full rank. Let's suppose this from here on.

If $A$ is one-to-one, then by (ii) of the lemma, applied for $G = A^H$ we have 
$$ \mathrm{Ran}(G) = \R^m \iff \ker G^H = 0$$
For $G = A^H$ this reads 
$$ \mathrm{Ran}(A^H) = \R^m \iff \ker A = 0 $$
as $A^{HH} = A$. Therefore $\mathrm{Ran}A^H = \R^m$ that is $A^H$ is onto. By (i) from the Lemma, again for $G = A^H$ we find a $\gamma$ such that (you incorrectly wrote $A^H$ here instead of $A$)
$$ \|Az\| \ge \gamma \|z\|, \qquad z \in \R^n $$
This gives, recalling that 
$$ \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<A^HAz, z> = \<Az,Az> = \|Az\|^2 $$
by definition of the adjoint, that 
$$ \<A^HAz,z> = \|Az\|^2 \ge \gamma^2 \|z\|^2 $$
Hence, $A^HAz \ne 0$ for $z \ne 0$, and therefore $A^HA$ is one-to-one. This implies $\det(A^HA) \ne 0$.